# Is it possible to make a link to an IRC channel?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

Out of curiosity, why does `[bla](ircs://chat.freenode.net/archlinux)` not produce a link? And I how can I actually make such a link work?

Comment: Probably because it assumes only http and https are links to prevent deeplinking, presumably for security reasons

Comment: Workaround: [Freenode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freenode) has a web interface, so you can always construct a "normal" URL for a direct link. Example, for [Sigrok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigrok): `https://webchat.freenode.net/#sigrok`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not possible and allowed protocols are restricted to HTTP(S) only.

From [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/)

> href attributes can only hold proper URL links, such as https://stackexchange.com/users/, or relative or protocol-relative URL links such as /q/3122 or //stackexchange.com/users/. They cannot hold other types of links, such as relative fragments (e.g. #3122), or protocols other than HTTP or HTTPS (e.g. javascript, ftp, or mailto): having any of these types of links in the href will result in the link being stripped out

I assume the same rules go for URLs used in CommonMark Markdown as it would be extremely weird if that would allow us to do more.

Not sure if that works for what you need it for, but you could create a code snippet that users need to run to be able to click your link, like so:

```js
// RUN ME! by clicking the run code snippet button
```

```html
<p>
<a href="ircs://chat.freenode.net/archlinux">To ArchLinux irc!</a>
</p>
<p>
<a href="news://news.example.com">Our news server!</a>
</p>
```

Comment: That code snippet seems like *major* overkill. [All programmers know how to copy-paste, right?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agflT.jpg)

Comment: @CodyGray I dunno. It might be overkill but if you really want a clickable link with that protocol then this is the only option. And yes, I have the book.